# Smaller and greater comparison in Python 3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, comparison

I see this code used on Python 2 library:

```
if a <> '0'
```

but in Python 3 it throws an error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Now I'm not totally sure if the comparison is similar to:

```
if a < '0' and a > '0'
```

Or does it mean something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If values of two operands are not equal, then condition becomes true. for example (1 <> 2) is true. **This is similar to != operator.** 
in your case use 
`if a != '0'`

Comment: Thanks, I just found it too from https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in. It was just hard to find with Google. Answer accepted.